# Change Bibliography name to "References" and add it to TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, naming

As title suggests. I have the following in my referencing section :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
 .
 .
 .
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}  
\bibliography{library}
```

And it prints :

[image]

I would like to change `Bibliography` to `References` -- And also add it to my table of contents.

Comment: Are you using `babel` with any language?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina not sure what `babel` is, don't think I'm using that.

Comment: @Werner thanks for pointing that out Werner. I will do better research next time before posting.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since `babel` is not being used, it's enough to redefine `\bibname`. For the inclusion of the bibliography in the ToC, one can use the [`tocbibind`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind) package. So, add these lines to the preamble:

```
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind} 
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
```

The options for `tocbibind` prevent the ToC, the LoF, and the LoT to be listed in the table of contents.

Comment: This did not work for me in  lyx v2.2

Comment: It conflicts with `\tableofcontents`