# Word "REFERENCE" and "Reference" in ToC and bibliography page in Thesis

Tags: table-of-contents, naming

I am writing thesis using template "**Easy thesis**" from ShareLaTeX. Now I have a problem in writing the title "Reference" in the last page of thesis and in the table of contents.

I want the word "**REFERENCE**" to be appear in capital letters in the table of content page, while the same word appear as "**Reference**" in the bibliography page.

I have searched around to get some hint. I tried as explained [Change Bibliography name to "References" and add it to TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108941/change-bibliography-name-to-references-and-add-it-to-toc). I also looked at [How to change the name of document elements like "Figure", "Contents", "Bibliography", "Appendix", etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/how-to-change-the-name-of-document-elements-like-figure-contents-bibliogr) and http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=704 but I could make this changes.

Hope to get some help from experts.

Comment: Well, I asked within my understanding. Anyway, I found solution to my problem. Those experience as my problem can refer there.(http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2851).

Comment: What you suggest in comment is exactly what is contained in [How to change the name of document elements like “Figure”, “Contents”, “Bibliography” etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993/5764) yet you mention in your original post that you "could [not?] make [these] changes." Without much to go on, I'm suggesting we close this question as being a duplicate of the linked post.